# Android download pdf from URL

Tags: android, pdf, httprequest, httpresponse, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a pdf from a URL where the pdf is part of the response stream rather that attaching it as part of the response. Below is the code that I tried but there is not much luck because when the pdf gets corrupted because there is some html content written inside. Not sure where the problem is.

```
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        // always check HTTP response code first
        System.out.println("resp: "+responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();
            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }
            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;
            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check this tutorial with code completely work and easy to understand. https://androidknowledgeblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/download-pdf-from-server-android/

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Apache's commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, java.io.File) to accomplish this task.

an example implementation would be:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "foo.pdf");
URL url = new URL("https://foosite.com/files/foo.pdf");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("http://foo"), f);
```

at this point, your File object will be ready for processing.

Reference:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: I have tried this method. The pdf file is still corrupt. :(

Comment: with your URL, try pasting it to your browser (to commence download) and see if the file is actually not corrupt...

Comment: the problem is that the pdf urls get redirected, thats why it is corrupted, because the downloaded file is an html of the redirection and not he pdf